# Issue with textview in swift 3

Tags: swift

I am working in a form in swift 3, my problem is when I tried to hide the keyboard in textview because the keyboard reuse to hide and is still visible in the previous VC.

My question is what I missing to fix this and when tap outside of textview the keyboard hide  automatically?

Here the code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return(true)
}
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if(textField == names){
    scrooView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:250), animated: true)
    }
    else if(textField == email){
        scrooView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:250), animated: true)
    }
    else if (textField == tel){
        scrooView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:250), animated: true)
    }
    else if (textField == message){
        scrooView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:450), animated: true)
    }
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: 

UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
        scrooView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: true)
}

extension UIViewController{
    func hideKeyboard(){
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

@objc func dismissKeyboard(){
    view.endEditing(true)
}

}
```

Here [a link with the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIvaB.jpg)!

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the UITextView delegate method properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a scrollView, try to add the GestureRecognizer in them, like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrooView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var tfTest: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrooView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard)))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard(){
    tfTest.endEditing(true)
}

})
```

If you add your Gesture in your View, it could never actived 'cause you are touching the scrollview that is over the view.

Comment: When I change it for scrooView give me this error `Use of unresolved identifier 'scrooView'`, I have it in the top of the VC like this: 
    `@IBOutlet weak var scrooView: UIScrollView!`

Comment: i changed my answer, i wrote an example, works for me.

Comment: Try to change this: `UITextField!` for `UITextView! ` in tfTest

Comment: Thank you Genaro...I saw my entire code and find and error that was making the keyboard reuse to hyde.